# "An den Mann, den..." or "An dem Mann, den..." - Which one correct?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative

At the beginning of a letter on the Internet addressing someone, do we use accusative or dative?
Which one is correct?

> An dem Mann, den...
>   An den Mann, den...

Comment: "den", but think again if you really want to write that letter.

Comment: Funny enough, although my browser only checks English spelling, the only word which is squiggled is the incorrect one ;)

Comment: You might want to use "An den _Herrn_", which some people may find a bit old-fashioned, but it certainly is more polite than "Mann". That way it doesn't sound so much like "To the man whom I saw pee in my front garden yesterday", which, ironically, is accusing accusative. Generally, it isn't overly polite, either way. Don't have a name?

Answer (score 5):

Many location-related prepositions go with the Dativ when a state/position is expressed, but with the Akkusativ when related to a direction or movement.

**An** is among them, **in** is also quite prominent. There is an [interesting overview here (even although it is from an Austrian site!)](http://www.graf-gutfreund.at/daf/02grammatik/04praeposition/gr1_praepositionen.pdf) (pdf).

So when you express **where to** (or **to whom**) the letter should be sent, it is **an den** (Akkusativ) for male recipients.

> An dem Mann kommt mir etwas komisch vor.
>
> *Something about the man seems strange to me.*

...would be a grammatically correct use of **an** + Dativ (although not necessarily the best way to express this, and not obviously location-related either.)

Further example:

> Das Bild hängt an der Wand. (describing where it is)
>
> Ich hänge das Bild an die Wand. (describing where I am putting it)

Comment: Was soll das "(even although it is from an Austrian site!)" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can ask *to whom* (*an wen*) it is always the accusative, so

> An den Mann, der

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a short form of

> [Dieser Brief ist] an den Mann [gerichtet], ...

Therefore

> An **den** Mann, ...

(What follows after the comma depends on content: "der mir gestern so nett geschrieben hat", "dessen Katze in meinen Garten gemacht hat", "dem das rote Auto gehört", "den alle mit George Cloney verwechseln")

Answer (score 0):

When `an` is used in a local, dynamical way (giving a direction) it is used with accusative.

> **An wen** ist der Brief gerichtet. Er ist **an den Mann** gerichtet.

For instance

> An **den** Mann, den ich liebe.
>   An **Herrn** Svengard